# C++ how to read a file and print certain part only to the screen

Tags: c++, file-io

I need my program to read a file with a format as following:

```
latitude,longitude,address,city,state,zip,phone,college,district,website
34.9438553,-120.4214783,800 S College Dr,Santa Maria,CA,93454, 805.922.6966,ALLAN HANCOCK COLLEGE, Allan Hancock Joint Community College District, www.hancockcollege.edu
38.649353,-121.3482895,4700 College Oak Dr,Sacramento,CA,95841, 916.484.8011,AMERICAN RIVER COLLEGE, Los Rios Community College District, www.arc.losrios.edu
34.6749175,-118.1843197,3041 W Avenue K,Lancaster,CA,93536, 661.722.6300,ANTELOPE VALLEY COLLEGE, Antelope Valley Community College District, www.avc.edu
35.4108801,-118.9736161,1801 Panorama Dr,Bakersfield,CA,93305, 661.395.4011,BAKERSFIELD COLLEGE, Kern Community College District, www.bakersfieldcollege.edu
34.8708435,-117.0210879,2700 Barstow Rd,Barstow,CA,92311, 760.252.2411,BARSTOW COLLEGE, Barstow Community College District, www.barstow.edu
37.8699917,-122.2700007,2050 Center St,Berkeley,CA,94704, 510.981.2800,BERKELEY CITY COLLEGE, Peralta Community College District, www.berkeley.peralta.edu
39.6462028,-121.6477912,3536 Butte Campus Dr,Oroville,CA,95965, 530.895.2511,BUTTE COLLEGE, Butte-Glenn Community College District, www.butte.edu
36.9915657,-121.9243927,6500 Soquel Dr,Aptos,CA,95003, 831.479.6100,CABRILLO COLLEGE, Cabrillo Community College District, www.cabrillo.edu
```

I want to console out only the latitude and longitude of each college, which is the first and second set of numbers separated by comma for each line.

i.e: 34.9438553 and -120.4214783 for S College Dr

I figured out how to read the whole text, but I could not figure out how to read only certain parts of the text.

Below is my first attempt, nothing fancy, just read the whole text because I did not know where to go from here. Please help me, I'm lost

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    string line;
    ifstream myfile ("cccGeoList.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while (!myfile.eof())
        {
            getline(myfile, line);
            cout << line << '\n';
        }
        myfile.close();
    }

    else cout << "Unable to open file";
```

Comment: @Duck Doesn't matter. He's shown us his attempt.

Comment: @Duck it's my school assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can discard the rest of the line after reading in the two values:

```
string latitude, longitude;
char dummy;

while (myfile >> latitude >> dummy >> longitude)
{
    std::cout << latitude << longitude << '\n';
    myfile.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

Update: In response to the comments, try this:

```
string line;
int i = 0;

myfile.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

while (std::getline(myfile, line, ','))
{
    std::cout << line;

    if (++i == 2)
    {
        myfile.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, it works ! except for I also wanted to omit the first line     "latitude,longitude,address,city,state,zip,phone,college,district,website4.9438553,-120.4214783,800"

Comment: @dodgerblue Then add `myfile.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n')` before the `while` loop.

Comment: and also it still printed the address

"34.6749175,-118.1843197,3041Avenue"

instead of "34.6749175,-118.1843197"

Do you mind explaining what does 

while (myfile >> latitude >> dummy >> longitude) 

 and  


myfile.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); mean

thanks a lot

Comment: what's ss, what library should I include?

Comment: @dodgerblue Oops! Replace `ss` with `myfile`.

Comment: almost perfect, but there's no space anywhere.
I tried using 

std::cout << line << '\n';

it prints 

34.9438553

-120.4214783

38.649353

-121.3482895

34.6749175

-118.1843197


still doesn't put the space in the right place.

Comment: @dodgerblue Then you need to put `line` into a stringstream, extract into another `std::string`, and print it out. Count the extractions just like I did in my example: if `count` is `2`, then print a new line. Replace `std::cout << line` in my code with that.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the first line,

I think you can do the following:

```
vector<double> latitude( N );
vector<double> longitude( N );
char commaChar;
while ( myfile >> latitude[i] >> commaChar >> longitude[i] ) // read the first part of line.
  myfile.ignore( 256, '\n' ); // ignore the rest part till end of line character.
```